# Derivative of $f(x)=x|x|$ at $x=0$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I am trying to show that $f(x) = x|x|$ is differentiable for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

By computing the prime derivative I get:
$$f^\prime (x) = |x|+x(|x|)^\prime$$
I know that 
$$(|x|)^\prime = \begin{cases} 
1 & \text{for } x > 0 \\
-1 & \text{for } x < 0
\end{cases}$$ and it's undefined for $x = 0$.  Thus $$f^\prime (x) = \begin{cases} 
2x & \text{for } x > 0 \\
-2x & \text{for } x < 0
\end{cases}$$

But what about $x = 0$? 
Looking at the graph I can see $f^\prime (0) = 0$ but how can I get there?

Thanks

Comment: Recognize that $x|x| = x^2$ for positive $x$ and $-x^2$ for negative $x$.  Take the derivative of both and check the limits as both go to 0.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you try to explicitly differentiate $|x|$ at $x=0$, you will run into trouble. Why not go back to the definition of the derivative:
$$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}.$$

Presumably the only interesting case is $x=0$:
$$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}.$$

What do you get as $h$ approaches $0$ from the left? From the right? Are these equal?

Comment: Thanks, I'll follow this suggestion, however I don't get why my approach doesn't work out well...

Comment: @Generalbrus The product rule only works if both terms are differentiable at the point in question. You cannot differentiate $x|x|$ at $0$ by writing $(x|x|)' = |x| + x|x|'$ and then plugging in 0 because $|x|$ is not differentiable at 0.